# How to record scores to be used later in code

Tags: python

I'm working on creating the game hangman and I want to be able to record what letters have been correct, and how many letters were incorrect, and then use this later to both write a message on the screen and end the game. How do I do this?

Currently, both `correct_guesses` and `incorrect_guesses` are lists, and every time there is a correct or incorrect guess the guess should be appended into its list.

```
import turtle
import string
import random
import time


words = ["gypsy"]


letter_width = 25
space_width = 15
incorrect_guesses = []
correct_guesses = []


def create_turtle():
    global tori
    tori = turtle.Turtle()
    tori.shape('classic')
    tori.pensize(5)
    tori.speed(.5)


def play_game():
    create_turtle()
    choose_word()
    draw_scaffold()
    draw_hints()
    draw_blanks()
    listen_for_keypress()


def report_incorrect_guess(letter):
    if letter not in incorrect_guesses:
        body_parts[len(incorrect_guesses)]()
        incorrect_guesses.append(letter)
        tori.penup()
        x = -270 + len(incorrect_guesses * letter_width)
        y = 200
        tori.goto(x, y)
        tori.color("black")
        tori.write(letter, font=("Times New Roman", 33, "normal"))


def report_correct_guess(letter):
    tori.penup()
    tori.color("black")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            offset = i * (letter_width + space_width)
            tori.goto(-245 + offset, -242)
            tori.write(letter, font=("Times New Roman", 33, "normal"))


def listen_for_keypress():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        screen.onkeypress((lambda l: lambda: on_key_press(l))(letter), letter)
    screen.listen()
    screen.mainloop()


def choose_word():
    global word
    word = random.choice(words)
    len(word)


def end_game(message):
    tori.pensize(50)
    tori.color("red")
    tori.penup()
    tori.goto(-150, 0)
    tori.pendown()
    tori.write(message)
    time.sleep(3)
    exit(0)


def on_key_press(letter):
    if letter in word:
        report_correct_guess(letter)
        if correct_guesses == len(word):
            end_game("YOU WIN! :)")
    elif letter not in word:
        report_incorrect_guess(letter)
        if incorrect_guesses == 9:
            end_game("YOU LOSE! X_X")
```

Right now, the game works fine until the end. Once you've correctly guessed all the letters, the game just keeps on playing, and you can guess more incorrect letters, but turtle just draws over the correct ones. Once all the body parts have been drawn, the game stays up, but an error message is shown that says that both these portions, specifically the parts pointed at, have issues.

```
def report_incorrect_guess(letter):
    if letter not in incorrect_guesses:
        body_parts[len(incorrect_guesses)]() <-----
        incorrect_guesses.append(letter)
        tori.penup()
        x = -270 + len(incorrect_guesses * letter_width)
        y = 200
        tori.goto(x, y)
        tori.color("black")
        tori.write(letter, font=("Times New Roman", 33, "normal"))

def on_key_press(letter):
    if letter in word:
        report_correct_guess(letter)
        if correct_guesses == len(word):
            end_game("YOU WIN! :)")
    elif letter not in word:
        report_incorrect_guess(letter) <------
        if incorrect_guesses == 9:
            end_game("YOU LOSE! X_X")
```

Comment: You should probably abbreviate your question to include only relevant details and code. It would be easier to read and assist you.

Comment: Issues? What issues?

Comment: I would write an `endGame` function which gets called at after each guess.  The function should check if the game is over (either a win or a loss) and then execute whatever you want to happen in each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the game from continuing past a certain point you can use a variable `gameOver` when the game ends let `gameOver = true`. In your `listen_for_keypress()` function your first test should be `if !gameOver`.  This way the game only runs while `gameOver = false`.

```
def on_key_press(letter):
    if letter in word:
        report_correct_guess(letter)
        if correct_guesses == len(word):
            gameOver = true
            end_game("YOU WIN! :)")
    elif letter not in word:
        report_incorrect_guess(letter)
        if incorrect_guesses == 9:
            gameOver = true
            end_game("YOU LOSE! X_X")

def listen_for_keypress():
    if !gameOver :
        screen = turtle.Screen()
        for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            screen.onkeypress((lambda l: lambda: on_key_press(l))(letter), letter)
        screen.listen()
        screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be changing anything. Do I need to tell it what to do once gameOver is false?

Comment: The condition I posted checks if `gameOver` is false and if it is false then the body of `listen_for_keypress()` will run.  So you will want to initially set `gameOver = false`.  With the code I provided you your `listen_for_keypress()` will only run if `gameOver = false`.